# Requesting to start process as administrator in Windows AS regular user

Tags: c#, c++, windows, security, winapi

I'm wondering how products like Avecto privilege guard accomplishes the task to start processes for a standard user with administrative privileges.
I guess that there is a service involved running as system and that in somehow plays a role in this but I am not familiar on how this would be done, process startup interception and modifying the token in someway? I don't have any code unfortunately cause I don't know where to start.

Comment: *I don't have any code unfortunately cause I don't know where to start.* -- That's why Avecto is paid big money -- they've done their research and obviously it isn't trivial in the work they do.

Comment: Windows suffers from a lot of privilege elevation holes even without Avecto. This clearly sounds like a bad idea. While it is not that difficult to implement.

Comment: Bad idea or not I am still interested if anybody still have something useful to say and not to tell me the obvious that Avecto has done their research. I am researching because I am personally interested in the internals of this process and not going to implement it by myself (seems like a bad idea to implement such a critical feature by myself when companies make their living out of this which i would think have more than one employee....)

Comment: Figuring out if they are using a service or scheduled task should not be that hard?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering how products like Avecto privilege guard accomplishes
>   the task to start processes for a standard user with administrative
>   privileges.

You can get started with understanding how native Windows API starts a process [running with administrator privileges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secbp/running-with-administrator-privileges).

To help develop secure software, we recommend that you use the following best practices when developing applications. ([Best Practices for the Security APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secbp/best-practices-for-the-security-apis))

> I'm wondering how products like Avecto privilege guard accomplishes
>   the task to start processes for a standard user with administrative
>   privileges.

Hope above resources help you to understand this.